# Prove that if $P = 2^m + 1$ is a prime then $Prob((g^x \bmod P) \bmod 2 = x \bmod 2) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm taking a cryptography class and this algebra problem was posed as optional homework:

> Prove that if $P = 2^m + 1$ is a prime and $g$ is a generator of its multiplicative group then $Prob((g^x \bmod P) \bmod 2 = x \bmod 2) = \frac{1}{2}$.

I experimented a bit and confirmed the result for $P = 17$ and $P = 257$. The parity of $g^x \bmod P$ looks rather random so I would guess that the argument should be somewhat "global" rather than constructive. I also noticed experimentally that:

> If $x \in \langle g^{2^k} \rangle$ where $ 1\leq k < m$  then $Prob(x \bmod 2 = 0) = \frac{1}{2}]$.

This seems significant, but I can't see why it happens. Note that proving this for $k = 1$ is actually sufficient for my question.

I am probably missing some basic group theory knowledge.

Thank you!

Later Edit: Changed some notation.

Comment: What does this notation $P\[...\]$ mean?

Comment: I intended it to mean $P[X]$ = probability of event $X$. I've edited the post to better reflect this, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @user714237 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod p$, we have
\begin{align}
g^{x+(p-1)/2}\bmod p
&=p-(g^x\bmod p)\\
&\equiv 1-(g^x\bmod p)\pmod 2
\end{align}
Thus if $\varphi(x)=((g^x\bmod p)-x)\bmod 2$, then
$$\varphi\left(x+\frac{p-1}2\right)=1-\varphi(x)$$
hence the function $x\mapsto x+\frac{p-1}2$ induces a bijection
$$\varphi^{-1}\{0\}\to\varphi^{-1}\{1\}$$
thus proving
$$\mathrm P[\varphi(x)=0]=\frac 12$$

Comment: Thank you! So the $P = 2 ^ m + 1$ part was a red herring I guess.

Comment: It's enough to assume $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$.